# Addressing multi-page table header rows in LiveCycle Designer

Tags: row, designer, livecycle

I am trying to dynamically hide a table column in LiveCycle Designer.  The table spans multiple pages, and there is a header row at the top of each page.  When I set the presence of the header row cell to "hidden", only the cell on the first page is hidden.  How do I hide the header row cells on subsequent pages?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by creating an additional section with its own sub-record detail to house what would span multiple pages and left the original section to house only the header record.

So the breakdown looked something like this in the Hierarchy pane:

```
MainForm
 +-MasterPage           (Main layout)
 +-subForm              (Layer over Main page)
   +-SubFormDetail      (Sub For on Layer)
     +-MainTable        (Primary Table)   
       +-HeaderSection  (Section to display first page only header)
       +-DetailSection  (Section to display multi-page rows)
         +-DetailRows   (Rows to display each records data)
```

Although admittedly this may not be the best method to accomplish what you are trying to do, it worked for my needs.

Hope that helps.